# Sorting based on the string : Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have created a list

```
let keywords = ['do', 'if', 'in', 'for', 'new', 'try', 'for','var'];
```

now I'm able to filter based on the string and I'm able to sort in descending and ascending order also.

But I'm unable to sort based on the string,

EX:- I need to sort the list with '**for**' (**for** needs to come on the top of the list and remaining will be as it is).

Comment: What exactly is your criteria for sort? Maybe you're looking to sort on filtered results. But that's something that's not really clear from your question.

Comment: so you are expecting something like 
['for,'for','do', 'if', 'in', 'new', 'try','var'];
??

Comment: yes exactly same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just need to change the callback of the sort function:

```
let keywords = ['do', 'if', 'in', 'for', 'new', 'try', 'for','var'];

const sortWithWord = (words, firstWord) => words.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a === firstWord) return -1;
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});

//will print  ["new", "do", "for", "for", "if", "in", "try", "var"]
console.log(sortWithWord(keywords, "new"));
```

The condition for sorting can be different of course, but if you want a certain word to be first, you'll have to return a negative value when it is compared.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to slice sorted list, like this:

```
keywords.sort();
var result = keywords.slice(keywords.findIndex(function(item){ return item == "for"; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let keywords = ['do', 'if', 'in', 'for', 'new', 'try', 'for','var'];
let spliceArray = keywords; //For this line there is for sure a more elegant solution.

const queryIndex = keywords.findIndex(entry => entry === 'for');

spliceArray.splice(queryIndex, 1);

const newKeywords = [keywords[queryIndex], ...spliceArray];
```